# Trying to install discord.py and it says "no module named pip"

Tags: python, linux

When running the command to install `discord.py`

```
python3 -m pip install -U discord.py
```

It says that there is no module named pip and thus I cannot complete the download or installation. I checked, and pip is installed on my machine. I am running Ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe http://askubuntu.com/questions/597906/how-to-install-pip-and-a-python-package-for-self-installed-python will guide you in the right direction

Comment: I know on Windows I have to be in the scripts directory to run pip as it is not on my path.  I do not know how it works on Ubuntu

Comment: Are you sure the `pip` version installed on your machine is for python3 and not python2? `pip` is specific to the python version.

Comment: The version for Python 3 is in an other package, AFAIR is was `python3-pip` or something similar.

Comment: Go download https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and do `python3 get-pip.py` (you may need to run as sudo)

Answer (score 0):

Just do `sudo apt-get python3-pip`

Then do `pip3 install -U discord.py`

Should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Do `sudo apt install python3-pip`

And then `pip3 install -U discord.py`

I would have just commented on the previous answer but I'm a guest